# Road taxes between Sofia and Berlin

Tags: driving, road-trips, taxes

me and my sis are trying to plan a road trip from Sofia, Bulgaria to Berlin, Germany. My question is does anyone know what are the road taxes at Serbia, Hungary, Slovakia, Czech republic and Germany for a car/mini bus(up to 9 people)?

Comment: Do you mean taxes, or do you mean Tolls?
Where will the vehicle be registered?

Comment: @CMaster I meant Tolls. The vihicle is registered in Bulgaria, but that does has anything to do with the tolls?

Comment: You asked regarding tax issues, for which registration might matter. Some tools may vary upon where teh vehicle is based.

Comment: @CMaster I understand the confusion and I'm sorry for the misleading question. Egil gave me a perfect answer, exactly what I needed to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Germany doesn't seem to impose a vignette on tourists.
Hungary - for minibus it's about 22€ for a week.
Both Slovakia and Czech Republic will require about 12€ for a 10-day vignette.
Serbia requires about 5-6€ per 100km, depending on the route - so, you'll need to calculate it for yourself.

Hope that helps.

P.S. [Eurovignettes.eu](https://www.eurovignettes.eu/) might be of use.

Comment: (+1) Germany has been talking about a general vignette for years and passed a law to that effect last year. It was supposed to take effect on January 1st, 2016 but has been postponed to wait for the results of a complaint from the EU Commission so indeed no vignette for the time being.

Comment: @Relaxed Thanks for the input, I somehow missed that